# Using UIGraphicsImageRenderer to resize UIImage to fixed pixel size

Tags: ios, swift

```
        func thumbImage(image: UIImage) -> UIImage {
            let cgSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
            let thumb = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: cgSize)
        
            return thumb.image { _ in
            image.draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: cgSize))
            }
        }
```

The final image is 300x300.
I would like, not matter the iPhone screen resolution, to have the image to be 100x100 (it is a square image of course).

How modify this code to achieve this result?

(I'm open to alternate ways of achieving this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func thumbImage(image: UIImage, pxWidth: Int, pxHeight:Int ) -> UIImage {
        let cgSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: pxWidth, height: pxHeight)
        let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: pxWidth, height: pxHeight)
        
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(cgSize, false, 1.0)
        image.draw(in: rect)
        let thumb = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        
        let compressedThumb = thumb!.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.70)
        
        return UIImage(data: compressedThumb!)!
        
    }
```

This alternative with UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions works and keeps the code as short as the initial one. (I also added some compression and conversion code).